# How to authenticate request made to camel webscoket

Tags: java, apache-camel, java-websocket

We are using camel web socket component for publishing real time data. We want to authenticate clients so if user is authorised then he/she should be able to access that websocket url. Please let me know is there any standard way which camel provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass on a unique key when new socket is opened.

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://example.com:port/uniquekey",'chat');
```

Then before the sending the handshake, extract the uniquekey from header and send the handshake if uniquekey passes necessary checks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/) with the corresponding [Camel component](https://camel.apache.org/shiro-security.html) to add authentication, authorization.